# Android StartActivity(Intent) -> NullPointerException (something to do with onclicklistener)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

This code stopped working and i don't understand why.
it returns this and crashes when it tries to perform StartActivity(Intent) [marked in code, inside OnClick]:

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)"

Here's the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView responseField;

private ScoresDataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    responseField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonScore).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd).setOnClickListener(this);

    datasource = new ScoresDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();


    List<Score> scores = datasource.getAllScores();

    ArrayAdapter<Score>
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Score>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            scores);
    setListAdapter(adapter);    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    ArrayAdapter<Score> adapter =
            (ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Score c = null;

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonScore:

            Intent scorePage = new Intent(this, ScoreboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(scorePage);
       //[CRASHES HERE]     <---------------


            break;
        case R.id.buttonAdd:

            EditText nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText scoreField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.score);
            String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            String score = scoreField.getText().toString();

            try {
                int scoreInt = Integer.parseInt(score);
                responseField.setText("SCORE RECEIVED: " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + name + "  " + score);
                c = datasource.createScore(score, name);
                adapter.add(c);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                responseField.setText("Not Valid Score");
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 break; }

}
}
```

This is xml sheet for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AddScore"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="187dp"
    android:text="Player"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="184dp"
    android:text="Score"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/score" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="226dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:text="ScoreBoard"
    android:id="@+id/buttonScore" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScoreboardActivity"
        android:label="Scoreboard" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Target Activity:

```
public class ScoreboardActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



private ScoresDataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores);

    findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete).setOnClickListener(this);

    datasource = new ScoresDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();


    List<Score> scores = datasource.getAllScores();

    ArrayAdapter<Score>
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Score>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            scores);

//Sorting
    adapter.sort(new Comparator<Score>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Score sc1, Score sc2) {
            return Integer.toString(sc1.getScore()).compareTo(Integer.toString(sc2.getScore()));         
        }
    });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    ArrayAdapter<Score> adapter =
            (ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Score c = null;
    Random r = new Random();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonBack:
        Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
            break;

        case R.id.buttonDelete:
            if(adapter.getCount()>0){
                c = adapter.getItem(0);
                datasource.deleteScore(c);
                adapter.remove(c);
            }
            break;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Show us your `activity_scores` xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that you're trying to set a click listener on a null object.

If you say the error fires when you start the next activity then on your `ScoreboardActivity` there is an error on trying to set the click listener for one of this views:

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Check your `activity_scores.xml` to see if you really have those ids.

Comment: Wow yea thats it, my xml button was named wrong. I feel stupid. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.